# How to detect whether a script is dot-sourced, or loaded as part of a module using powershell v2+?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Given a ps1 file as part of a module with the following code:

```
function Get-Greeting {
    'Hello {0}' -f $Env:Username
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function:Get-Greeting
```

When loaded as part of the module, everything is fine. If I dot-source the script, I get

```
Export-ModuleMember : The Export-ModuleMember cmdlet can only be called from inside a module.
```

I know I could just add a -ErrorAction:Ignore on the Export-ModuleMember, but that's not the point. I'd like to have a script run differently whether it has been imported, or dot-sourced.

In version 2, one could probably write a hack around the `$PSScriptRoot`, but that is just a hack, and doesn't work in version 3 where they "fixed" `$PSScriptRoot` to never be null. I've tried looking at various items in `$MyInvocation`, but either I've missed something, or it has nothing useful.

I've also tried to run `Get-Variable` inside and outside a module, but again found no differences.

What have I missed that is different when running as `Import-Module` vs `. myscript.ps1`?

Comment: If you want a module, do a module, if you want a dot sourceable script do that instead. Why would you need both at the same time?

Comment: Sometimes, I just want one part of a module loaded, instead of the whole thing. For example, we have a utility module at work where one portion uses the SMO libraries, which have a slow init, and load other crap in the environment. I don't want to split each set of functionality into a separate module, but would like to selectively load a function set.

Comment: Also, it's simple to detect dot-source vs script invocation, why not module vs dot-source vs script invocation?

Comment: You can't partially load a module. If you want that, you need to split the funcitonality into several modules.

Comment: Why not create one or more separate ps1 files containing your functions, that are dot-sourced by your module? That allows you to dot-source them from anywhere else as well... Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I found the answer to this. I was missing something in `$MyInvocation`, because I was looking in the wrong scope. Given the following files:

```
# .\moduleDetection\moduleDetection.ps1
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; 
'=== Parent Invocation.MyCommand: [{0}]' -f (Get-Variable -Name:MyInvocation -Scope:1 -ValueOnly | Select -Expand MyCommand) | Out-Host;
```

.

```
# .\moduleDotSource\moduleDotSource.psm1
. "$PSScriptRoot\..\moduleDetection\moduleDetection.ps1"
```

.

```
# .\module-test.ps1
$Error.Clear()

Write-Host "Powershell Version 3:"
Write-Host "Powershell -Command Import-Module (direct)"
powershell -nologo -noprofile -Command { Import-Module .\moduledetection }

Write-Host "Powershell -Command Import-Module (dot-source)"
powershell -nologo -noprofile -Command { Import-Module .\moduleDotSource }

Write-Host "Powershell -File ...moduledetection.ps1"
powershell -nologo -noprofile -File .\moduledetection\moduleDetection.ps1

Write-Host "Powershell Dot-Source"
powershell -nologo -noprofile -Command { . .\moduledetection\moduleDetection.ps1 }

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Powershell Version 2:"
Write-Host "Powershell -Version 2 -Command Import-Module"
powershell -version 2.0 -nologo -noprofile -Command { Import-Module .\moduledetection }

Write-Host "Powershell -Version 2 -Command Import-Module (dot-source)"
powershell -version 2.0 -nologo -noprofile -Command { Import-Module .\moduleDotSource }

Write-Host "Powershell -Version 2 -File ...moduledetection.ps1"
powershell -version 2.0 -nologo -noprofile -File .\moduledetection\moduleDetection.ps1

Write-Host "Powershell -Version 2 Dot-Source"
powershell -version 2.0 -nologo -noprofile -Command { . .\moduledetection\moduleDetection.ps1 }
```

and finally, make a symlink from the original ps1 to a psm1 with the correct name to load as a direct module.

```
cmd /c mklink .\moduledetection\moduleDetection.ps1 .\moduledetection\moduleDetection.psm1
```

The output shows that the parent scope has the key.

Output:

```
Powershell Version 3:
Powershell -Command Import-Module (direct)
=== Parent Invocation.MyCommand: [ Import-Module .\moduledetection ]
Powershell -Command Import-Module (dot-source)
=== Parent Invocation.MyCommand: [ Import-Module .\moduleDotSource ]
Powershell -File ...moduledetection.ps1
Powershell Dot-Source

Powershell Version 2:
Powershell -Version 2 -Command Import-Module
=== Parent Invocation.MyCommand: [ Import-Module .\moduledetection ]
Powershell -Version 2 -Command Import-Module (dot-source)
=== Parent Invocation.MyCommand: [ Import-Module .\moduleDotSource ]
Powershell -Version 2 -File ...moduledetection.ps1
Powershell -Version 2 Dot-Source
```

As we can see from the output shown (run on Server 2008 R2), the parent scope's `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` contains the import module statement. I have not tested it yet, but I infer from this that if it's multiple indirection through chained dot-sourcing, we can keep taking the parent scope until we get either Null or an Import-Module.

Now we know how to detect if we're in a module or not, and through other resources can also grok if we're being dot-sourced, executed directly, and/or loaded through a module.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question but may help you achieve your goal.

Use the `-Function` or `-Cmdlet` parameters of `import-module` to selectively import parts of the module.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725.aspx

> `-Function<String[]>`
>
> Imports only the specified functions from the module into the current session. Enter a list of functions. Wildcard
>   characters are permitted. Some modules automatically export selected
>   functions into your session when you import the module. This parameter
>   lets you select from among the exported functions.
>
> `-Cmdlet<String[]>`
>
> Imports only the specified cmdlets from the module into the current session. Enter a list of cmdlets. Wildcard characters
>   are permitted. Some modules automatically export selected cmdlets into
>   your session when you import the module. This parameter lets you
>   select from among the exported cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been doing something similar, but I have a 'build' step that collapses all the separate scripts into a .psm1 file for use as a module.

In that case the code either runs in it's own .ps1, *or* runs as a .psm1, so you simply need the following:

```
# at the end of some-function-library.ps1
if($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name.EndsWith('.psm1')){
    Export-ModuleMember -Function:*-SomePrefix*
}
```

(Why? I find the seperate scripts much easier to manage, debug, version etc..., but the .psm1 is obviously easier to distribute)