# PowerShell - Dot-sourcing "scripts having $PSScriptRoot references" from a function

Tags: function, powershell, scripting

My question is the exact same question as the [Dot-sourcing functions from file to global scope inside of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187510/dot-sourcing-functions-from-file-to-global-scope-inside-of-function) but with one exception

The solution in the above question works great and I am using it except when the scripts have variables like **$PSScriptRoot** that rely on the physical location of the script, the path is empty (and defaults to c:\).

The functionality in some of my scripts rely on the location of the script itself (e.g., to log to relative path folders, run a ".sql" file within the same folder, email a "html" file in the same folder etc..). My scripts are also not in a single folder. There is a hierarchical structure.

I saw this other question [Dot Source a "script" within a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713844/dot-source-a-script-within-a-function) where using modules was recommended but I would end-up having the same issue unless the relative path reliance in code is redone.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Update 2/6/2015:** Please see my comment also dated 2/6/2015. This is the code that I used to come-up with a temporary hack that works

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $BasePath -recurse -Filter $FilePattern `
 | Where-Object { Get-Content $_.FullName -Head $Head | Select-String -Pattern $StringPattern -SimpleMatch } `
 | forEach { `
    Write-Verbose "Dotsourcing file - $($_.FullName)"

    $script = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw; `
    $script = $script -Replace 'function\s(\w+)','function Global:$1'; `

    $file = $_.FullName.Replace('.ps1','.tmp.ps1')
    Set-Content -Path $file -Value $script -Force
    . $file
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $file -Force
  }
```

Comment: you can try to get the current script path with `$myinvocation.mycommand.path`

Comment: This would work for a script but I need to get the path from inside a function that lives in a dot-sourced script. The calling function/script could be in a different location. Also, I need this to be viewable when debugging interactively and .path is not supported in ISE. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742354/myinvocation-mycommand-path-returning-null

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867953/how-to-detect-whether-a-script-is-dot-sourced-or-loaded-as-part-of-a-module-usi/18728609#18728609

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helps but the problem remains. Please remember that the scripts are loaded-up using the original suggesion
$script = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw; `
$script = $script -Replace 'function\s(\w+)','function Global:$1'; `
$result = .([scriptblock]::Create($script));  
I tried the local and parent scopes. Local scope is empty for functions loaded in the above fashion. The calling parent scope is good if it is a script in the same folder but it may not be the case all the time.

Comment: I have a temporary solution that works. Basically, from the function that recursively dot-sources .ps1 files, I open the .ps1 script and replace the function name to have a "Global:" prefix, save it out to a temporary file in the same folder as the original, dot-source it and remove the temporary file. Since the temp file is placed in the same folder as the original, the $PSScriptRoot works when the function is called later. The "Global:" prefix ensures that the visibility for the function is beyond the scope of the wrapper function that recursively dot-sources. Will post code in next comment